# Mist wallet crashes when importing/dropping wallet file

Tags: mist, wallets, bug

After dropping the UTC--2017-06-07T19-18-29 file on a fresh Mist 0.8.10 install, Mist automatically closes.
Is this a known issue?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, every time I open Mist it starts downloading the blockchain data over and over also. I'm terrified of deleting the wrong things and not being able to load my wallet though

Comment: reinstall don't work?

Comment: Same here, just exits the program after trying to import on both my computers, windows 10